# What use does Pre-war Money have in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

Pre-war Money has a base value of 10 caps in Fallout 3, and a weight of 0.  Obviously, it's a good thing to collect and trade in for caps.  Are there any NPCs who value Pre-war Money more than the average merchant?  Or, really, is there any use for Pre-war Money besides just selling it to a regular merchant?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't have any special uses (well, if you don't count the Rock-It launcher...)

[Pre-War Money at fallout wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pre-war_money)

Answer (score 14):

If you get bored, you can always try to make piles of this fun/useless stuff and stage your own screenshots.

I found a great example in [this thread](http://community.us.playstation.com/thread/233636):

[image: Pre-War Money Pile Up]

Comment: Haha I'm doing that as well. I also have an army of garden gnomes :)

Comment: Dude sweet pic of the pile of pre-war money, but the best thing to do is judt keep them in a filing cabinet at your Megaton home. Once you get like 100 just sell them, oh and also keep a stash of stimpaks and bobby pins in there. I also keep pre-war books in it until I have like 50 then sell them, but that's optional. (Trust me I've beaten the game and the stash of srtims and bobby pins really helps later on towards the end of the story mode.)

Comment: @user15796 - The only item I would put away in your list is the pre-war book, as it has a weight value, and you don't lose your items on death, so you may as well keep the bobby pins and pre-war money with you. Also, running out of bobby pins has never been an issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

Its only use is selling for caps.

Comment: Also note that with a weight of 0 and value of 10, it's a very good item to sell for caps.

Answer (score 5):

It is a good 'secondary currency' along with Cigarettes. Since vendors run out of caps easily, it is sometimes useful to have something you can convert your heavier items into for transport until you meet another vendor, or they get more caps. Prewar money works quite well for this, though due to the buying and selling you won't get full value.

Comment: This remains true in New Vegas, which also introduces NCR money and Legion money for the same purpose.